# How similar does a question need to be to another to be marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070935/java-get-a-randomly-generated-string-from-one-method-to-another) has been dupe-hammered by Jens earlier today. It has been reopened (and reclosed) since; but my question about the validity of dupe votes remains.

Quick summary of the question: OP generates a String in one method and wants to make it accessible to another.

Quick summary of the dupe link: OP asks how to compare Strings in Java.

I believe these two have nothing in common with each other.

Jens argument for the dupe vote is based on one line in the code which I believe is not at main point of the question:

`if(LetterString == PressedKey){`

Which is how OP of the linked question tries to compare the Strings. Besides, that is not even currently relevant because `LetterString` does not contain the updated value (which is what the question really is about).

My question: Is that a good enough reason for a close vote/hammer? Is the degree of similarity that small to cast a duplicate vote?

Below is the conversation Jens and me had in the comments regarding this (in case they are removed/moved to chat):

> [image: Conversation]

Comment: No worries, found another million dupes to close it with.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Impressive, and they're all proper duplicates too!

Comment: And yet even with all this evidence of no research effort...

Comment: you should edit and apply to reopen this post.. bahaha.. ironic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My take on this:

It's all about the answers, and less the questions.

If your question can be answered by an answer on another post, you can mark it as a duplicate, even if the question doesn't look similar on the eye (it's useful to add an explanation, though).

If the concept you're failing to grasp is explained in an answer on another post, you can mark it as a duplicate, even if the question doesn't look similar.

If there's a similar question, but the answer is not applicable to the question you want to mark, you shouldn't mark it as a duplicate.

Keep in mind that even wielders of the dupehammer and reviewers of close votes are just people. They make mistakes, and are sometimes too eager to close a question. Especially if you haven't specified what you know and what you've tried, they might think it's a duplicate while it isn't.

Also keep in mind that broad or vague questions sometimes get marked as a duplicate of other broad questions (I often see it, but I'd rather see them closed as too broad or unclear, even if they might've been previously answered). The answer may not be applicable, but that's because the one closing it couldn't identify the exact issue, and thought it was.

Relevant links:

- [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/)
- [Help section on closed
  questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) (Yivi)
- [Project Reduplication of Deduplication Has Begun!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286329/project-reduplication-of-deduplication-has-begun) (Braiam)

Comment: I didn't know we closed questions as duplicated because the answers...

Comment: @Braiam Well, that has been my belief. That's also why you can't mark a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question (with meta as an exception where that is allowed, and repeat questions by the same user as another example).  [Global meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/) states that questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers, but isn't that specific.

Comment: @Braiam, of course we dupe-close based on the answers. What matters is where you can find the answer for the dupe.

Comment: Lets see what the message for duplicate says "This **question** was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing **question**." Nothing about answers.

Comment: @Braiam From [Closed Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): _This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question**_. (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @yivi I will answer every unanswered question with the same answer and say that all of them are duplicates because the only answer is the same for all the questions. Oh, and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286329/213575)

Comment: @yivi "question asked before" the rest is explanatory yet not binding. Duplicate *questions*, not duplicate answers. Closed questions, not closed answers.

Comment: Whatever @Braiam. The consensus is pretty firm on this one. Dupe-closing is always about the answers, not the question.

Comment: @yivi so *ad populum*, not even *ad auctoritatem*

Comment: @Braiam You can also note that the duplicate message says _This question already has an answer here: {duplicate link}_ . That would be pretty silly if it wasn't about the answers, and the question isn't answered there at all. I might've exaggerated a bit, but still (and SO is a community website, _ad populum_ is valid here if no authority has given a clear answer).

Comment: that's difficult for intermediate users, let alone new coders, to know.. while understandable if the old post can directly resolve your situation, but it is not always the case.. it often takes at least some familiarity and know-how to make a code fit your needs; and not just in changing variables/paths.. extra commands and adjusted code structuring.. some are too eager to downvote and shame; why a lot of decent answers are left to the comments, no one wants to lose rep

Comment: @physlexic If the solution to the duplicate doesn't actually solve their problem, then they merely need to edit the question to explain why the duplicate doesn't work for their situation, and the post can be reopened.

Comment: @servy i agree.. but majority of those policing posts are very experienced with lots of rep.. its hard to understand, let alone explain, why a post doesn't resolve your issue, especially if you don't fully understand the concept.. and many are punished for it by being down-voted and accused of not trying or doing any research.. its obvious for us to see that if they started [here] they could have figured it out, at least partially, but knowing where to start is often the hardest part

Comment: @physlexic If they can't explain why the solution doesn't solve their problem, then we can't help them.  There is nothing for anyone to do if they can't explain what problem they're having.  If they asked a question without doing the appropriate research then those posts *merit* downvotes.  If they did the research but failed to explain what they found and why it doesn't work for them, then again, the post merits a downvote.

Comment: @servy my understanding that this sit was not exclusive to CS majors.. i am mistaken

Comment: @physlexic My understanding was that this site wasn't for mind readers that don't need to have a description of the problem in order to provide a solution for it.  I guess I was mistaken, apparently CS majors are the only people that aren't able to have their minds read.

Comment: @servy ok, relax man.. im not saying you're wrong.. the site is set up this way for a reason.. my point was that the semi-elitist practice of top contributers shaming people who are trying to learn [as opposed to those just asking for scripts], snowballs into over policing because no one wants to be mistaken as the latter.. its great that they let you edit to fix posts, but who goes back to see that others have fixed their post, then remove their down vote.. no one cares about that, so it's pointless

Comment: @physlexic You think that it's elitist to say that I'm not literally capable of reading minds and solving a problem without knowing what the problem is?  That's...just not reasonable in the slightest.  If a post isn't answerable, editing it to actually be answerable is *necessary* for it to get an answer.  Don't do it to get a downvote reversed for the sake of 2 rep, do it so you can actually get an answer to your question.  If you *actually* fix a post, and turn it into a good one, it will start attracting upvotes, which will more than compensate for any downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

Two questions are never going to be identical. When I dupehammer a question closed, I mean one or both of these two things:

- Your question is answered by the answers to this other question. You would have learned what you needed to know by searching, and that is what you should have done (and should do before asking a question from now on).
- Your question, as posed, is sufficiently like this other question that it adds nothing to the mix. Perhaps you don't like or understand the answers there, but all your question does is effectively whine about that; nothing in your question would elicit a different answer.

In both cases the new question is a bad use of space and my ultimate goal is to get it back off Stack Overflow. And in both cases I have another goal, namely to teach the questioner to be a better Stack Overflow community member.

Comment: There is also another reason for duplicate-voting: "Your question is good, and it is answered by the answers to this other question. You couldn't find your answer by searching, but I could, because I am the expert. So you enjoy the existing good answers, people don't waste time writing inferior duplicate answers, and everyone is happy."

Answer (score 4):

When I'm considering duplicates I tend to ask myself if another user of the site searching for terms that would lead to "this question" would find their answer in the answers to "this other question".

So it doesn't matter to me if the questions are the same, or if the answers happen to answer both questions (for the same reasons that showing one's workings is necessary in an exam, you can get the same answer through different reasoning, and the reasoning might be the important part). It's if searching for something that would lead you to the "dupe" would be answered in the "original".

Askers often don't know the right question to ask, and that's okay, we can point them to the question they should have been asking that has already been answered in a way that will help them.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with the current answer by Erik. In my opinion, a duplicate is fundamentally about the question being the same, not the answers.

To quote [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/311163) by Tim Post:

> Remember: duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to
>   fundamentally identical problems - many questions have similar or
>   identical answers but are not duplicates. By the same token, many
>   questions are asked using very different wordings but seek to solve
>   identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a
>   solution even when they don't know what terms to search for.

Comment: You're missing the point of your own quotation. _"a solution to fundamentally identical problems"_ is the key. _"similar or identical answers but are not duplicates"_ is the response to "So you mean 'What is 3+5?' and 'What is the square root of 64?' are duplicates now?" which is a straw man that gets carted out every time we talk about this.

Comment: @JoshCaswell "**many questions have similar or identical answers but *are not duplicates***" do you really think so?

Comment: Also "Gold tag badge holders know when **something has been asked before**, at least generally" note the lack of "answer" in the entire comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#comment763171_231212

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable pair of questions that is fundamentally different but requires the exact same answer. Is this now going to be a long discussion about a hypothetical use-case? And even if there would be such a pair of questions: What is then your preferred way of handling it? Copying over the answer because they shouldn't be closed as duplicates?

Comment: @BDL I have seen questions about a general case closed as duplicates of a very specific case because someone posted the general case answer to the specific question. I don't think that should ever happen.

Comment: Then expand your answer and state explicitly how you want such questions to be handled.

Comment: I don't really like the following argument, but your reputation level is way before you get access to the relevant queues and actions. The answer is just stating what you don't want to happen but misses to say what instead should happen and how this should be reflected in the review behavior. There is, for example, no (community) way of moving answers.

Comment: @BDL I'll try to write up what I think and the cases I'm thinking of in more detail when I have some time. But I just think it's fairly obvious that someone providing a massively overkill answer to a specific question does not mean the general question is a dupe of the specific one.

Comment: I generally agree with you that two questions shouldn't have the same answer unless they are actually the same, but when someone is closing a question because the linked dupe has a borderline off topic answer with 1 vote 5 answers down from the accepted one that works, something has gone wrong.

Comment: @mbrig So what problem would that actually cause?  Why does a question having some unnecessary specificity that isn't actually relevant to the answers mean it shouldn't be a duplicate of some other question that omits that unnecessary information?  The questions are still fundamentally the same questions.

Comment: @Servy The specificity is not always unnecessary. I had a question about how to take the Cartesian product of an unknown number of lists (ans: LINQ magic) closed as a dupe of a question asking to take the Cartesian product of two lists (top answer: nested for loop). I nearly edited to ask to reopen before I saw a single vote answer at the bottom of the page showing what to do in my case. IMO this would be like closing a question about how to do multiple inheritance as a dupe of a single inheritance question because someone happened to explain the multiple case in a different answer.

Comment: More generally, If two questions are in fact the same, why can that not be seen from the text of the question itself? Is it not possible the "same" answer has been applied to a question where it doesn't really fit?

Comment: @mbrig In that case the answers to the question in the duplicate aren't answering the question closed, so it doesn't merit closure, because the answers really are answering a different question.  Of course there are a million *actual* duplicates of that problem, so in that case just edit the duplicate list to get a real one.

Comment: @mbrig The problem with that is that you end up with people constantly claiming that questions aren't duplicates just because the questions have differences irrelevant to the solution to the problem.  If a question has been given an answer that's not appropriate to the question, then that is indeed a problem; the way to deal with that is to downvote it.  If the question has no good answers to the actual question asked it shouldn't be eligible for closure as a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy That's fair. I'm going to mull over my thoughts for a bit and see. I don't think I fundamentally disagree with you, perhaps just a matter of where the dupe/not dupe line is drawn.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate this. Marking a question as a duplicate has two purposes: (1) to reduce duplication of information, and (2) to allow the person to quickly find an answer to their question that has already been vetted by the community. So, of course it's all about the answers. Obviously the question is relevant and must be considered, but "duplicate" definitely is closer to "has already been answered here" than "someone already asked *exactly the same question*".