# Wording of guidance for OP on a duplicate question

Tags: feature-request, status-review, closed-questions

On a closed duplicate, the OP currently sees the following at the top of the question:

[image]

In my opinion, the box is poorly worded and doesn't provide the correct information on what the OP should do next. The box allows the user to either:

- Ask a new question (if the duplicate doesn't resolve their question)
- Edit question (no guidance provided why they should do this)
- Delete question

Specifically, I don't agree with asking the OP to ask a new question if the duplicate doesn't resolve their problem. Shouldn't they be advised to edit their current question and highlight the difference, as recommended at https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates.

Questions that are edited within five days of being closed are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review. As a result, I would suggest the following guidance provided in the box for the OP:

> Your question has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn't resolve your question, edit your question to highlight the difference. Your question will be placed in a review queue to determine whether it should be reopened.
>
> Read more about [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and what it means if a question is [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions#:%7E:text=If%20your%20question%20is%20closed,a%20user%20with%20sufficient%20reputation.).

Comment: Re: *"Ask a new question (if the duplicate doesn't resolve their question)"* - That was never how I'd read that, I'd read that as an invitation to ask an _entirely_ new question, as in, to keep using the site, not as an invitation to ask a new question which explains why the old one wasn't a duplicate... Although looks like the exact wording of the guidance has changed to make that.... certainly not the case

Comment: (For reference to the above, the text was previously: *"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."*)

Comment: @Nick I don't read what you're reading. I read: Press the "New Question" button and ask it again.

Comment: @Scratte I'm referring to the old text (which I wasn't aware was changed until this question as I don't tend to ask questions and so don't see personal dupe closures), you know, back when it actually prompted users to edit questions...

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I misunderstood :( I feel left out of the loop too. I suppose the only way to really know is to ask Questions that gets closed. I can't find a meta post that gives an overview of the full text and include the actual links of the various close notices.

Comment: I agree with the fundamental premise, but one misgiving I have about the "edit your question to highlight the difference" prompt is you get a lot of questions with meta-commentary like "**EDIT**: I looked at the duplicate and it didn't answer my question" etc. The edits should be content-oriented, not meta-explanations and OP should interact in the comments section to explain why the dupe is inaccurate (although this doesn't review queue it) along with an edit to the content to distinguish it and requeue it.

Comment: There's a [discussion on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951/622284) about this subject.

Comment: Prefer the original wording. If the question really isn't a duplicate, it's rare that the question is reopened even if OP explains how it is different([just like mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400284/hiding-votes-from-askers-only-for-a-specified-period)). Even if the question is reopened, it won't get the  new question exposure. Of course there will be a few rotten apples here and there, who will just keep on asking: We have downvotes and postbans for that.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-vote-to-close-questions-and-be-welcoming-at-the-same-time. For my intentions when dupehammering and my desired wording, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358763/how-similar-does-a-question-need-to-be-to-another-to-be-marked-as-a-duplicate/358783 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-vote-to-close-questions-and-be-welcoming-at-the-same-time/366779

Comment: @TheMaster If it **_isn't_** a dupe, then instead of deleting and asking again, they need to edit. This advice is confusing and against SO's rules.

Comment: Closely related MSO post - [Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401721/should-i-really-ask-the-same-question-again-if-the-old-one-was-closed-as-a-dupli)

Answer (score 32):

I agree with everything said. So not much noise from me more here.

A few things bunched together:

1. "Ugly" Questions should be edited, not freshly reposted in the same state (which the current wording implies IMHO - Not even a word about doing any kind of improvement when posting a new question).
2. Teaching OPs of closed questions more about how reopening works and that if they edit their question and show where the differences are between the duplicate and their question, then it's likely their question is reopened. This is based on my experience so far. One of the most common reasons why closed questions get abandoned is that OPs tend to think: If the post is closed, everything is over. Editing my closed question seems like only a waste of time - which is not true at all.

There was also a similar Meta post a few weeks ago [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400273/12139179), where I also covered some [similar aspects](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400298/12139179).

My suggestion:

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If that question doesn't resolve your issue, [edit your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788)<sup>1</sup> to highlight the difference between the associated question and yours. If edited, your question will be reviewed by other users<sup>2</sup> to determine whether it should [be reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).
>
> Find out more about [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and why your question [has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

<sub>1) This link can be replaced by https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing, but I think the FAQ post on Meta SE is more helpful.</sub>

<sub>2) It is not only the folks at the review queue who can revise a post. Also explaining about a review queue might be providing too much information, resulting in unnecessary confusion and distraction. IMHO adding "by other users" is important to make OPs see that more than one other user will judge whether the question is to be reopened and not only a single absolute voice, which I think makes editing more attractive to the OP.</sub>

Comment: + for the teaching. Pointing to resources is great. Guiding is kind and very useful.

Comment: +1 I agree with the second sub dialogue. It's already difficult enough to explain to new users what this is, and what that is. Why add more confusion? It's a shorter message, and unnecessary. And it's also analogous with the edit queue explanation.

Answer (score 9):

I mostly agree, though "Your question will be placed in a review queue to determine whether it should be reopened." is way too technical. "**Your question will be reviewed and might be reopened**." does the job.

Comment: Where words `reviewed` and `reopened` are hyrerlinks to FAQ entries regarding topics.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the main problem with this feedback is that we close two questions as duplicates not because they are similar questions, but because they have the same answer. The consequences of failing to synchronize access to DOM methods, for example, can be many and varied, and therefore many questions can have the answer "you need to synchronize your calls on the DOM"; the questions (and the symptoms) may be very different, but we treat them as duplicates because they all have the same answer.

So rather than "has been associated with a similar question" I would say "has the same answer as another question".

Comment: @TheCodesee and Michael This is already clear from the post notice, which doesn't say "This question is a duplicate of this linked question", but that "**This question already has answers here**" in bold.

Comment: @TheMaster But it goes on to say "has been linked to a *similar question*". So it starts off clear, and then muddies the waters.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the current message for duplicates is poorly written. Say there is Person ***x***, who has had a question closed as a duplicate (wrongly).

With the current message in place, I assume this is what ***x*** would think:

> Damn it! They just closed my question even though the duplicate doesn't help me at all. So let's see, it says to ask a new question, and to delete this one. Hmmm, okay then!

Which is the incorrect guidance, of course. The correct thing to do in that situation would be to edit the question to explain ***why*** the duplicate doesn't answer the OP's question.  I think we've established this.

Here is what I would have the message look like:

> Your question has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, edit your question immediately to highlight the difference.
> Your peers will then review your question to see if it should be reopened.
>
> Read more about [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and what it means if a question is [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions#:%7E:text=If%20your%20question%20is%20closed,a%20user%20with%20sufficient%20reputation.).

The reason why I think it should omit the details about the review queue is because it's just too complicated. Really all we need to explain is that trusted users (otherwise known as >3k users) will review it and decide whether or not to reopen the question.

It's explaining the same thing in fewer words, and it's also less complicated for people to understand. Plus, if you look at the explanation of suggested edits,

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer-reviewed.

So it calls for better consistency and it's easier to understand.