# Possible contradiction in whether to delete a question (with answers) closed as a duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, user-experience, vote-to-delete

Today, I asked a question ... after doing a search that yielded no relevant questions ... that was flagged as duplicate. It was very helpful to go to the duplicate post, but I ran into contradicting instructions on how to handle my duplicate question.

The notice of the duplication contains a link to delete the question, as if that were a suggested action. But, when I tried to delete it, a message popped up that suggested I would be rude to the folks who answered me if I deleted it. I agree.

To elaborate further, the Edit option is blue and in a border. The Delete option is in red with no border. It looks like the two are equal (side-by-side with same size font) with the Edit being the default. But, in reality, the Delete function is not recommended in this case, because of the answers.

Maybe the delete should either not be there or be marked as "not recommended" to avoid confusion.[image]

Another simple fix option would be to have the function link UI different in the case of a question with answers than on a question with no answers.

Comment: That message should be fixed, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400960/12708583) for more detail. You should try to instead improve it, as yivi said.

Comment: @Nick I've added example from my -9 duplicate - indeed it has "Delete question" button (that "Delete question" is actually a pink button showing up when you hover over). You probably looking at 3k+ version of the message on someone else post, not your own.

Comment: Also surprisingly my version does not even have the "Edit" button (unlike the one shown in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400960/wording-of-guidance-for-op-on-a-duplicate-question) question) ... not sure if it is gone for good, not showing due to the  question's age or due to being closed by the author as duplicate.

Comment: I added additional information that may (or may not) set my question as different from previous questions. I'm guessing that my experience is related to implementation of the recent policy change of not having questions with answers deleted.